# How do you open a link in a new window?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my website: jahde.co/stream. I want the "About Me>>jahde.co" link to open in a new window but it's not working (target="_blank").  Additionally how do would I delete the other "About Me" sidebar link that is going to another page (not the external website)?.

```
       <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>

            <?php if (!empty($options['twitter_username'])): ?>
                <li class="link email"><a href="http://jahde.co" target="_blank">About Me</a></li>
                <li class="link twitter">
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo $options['twitter_username'] ?>">@<?php echo $options['twitter_username'] ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Is there some javascript applied to that element that is preventing its default behavior?

Comment: target="_blank" should do it... if that link is on the screen, its either javascript nuking the behaviour like @MikeBrant said, or your html is not valid. Or do you mean you want it in a new window instead of a new tab?

Comment: Sometimes browser settings disable the ability to open links in a new page/tab. Try another browser, check settings.

Comment: The actual source code on your page doesn't have ``target="_blank"`` included... Perhaps you wrote it in a different part of your code which is not actually being used?? You should get in the habit of checking what your actual URL is showing, by looking at the source from your BROWSER.

Answer (score 5):

Your element on your site looks like:

```
<a href=​"http:​/​/​jahde.co/​stream/​sample-page/​">​About Me​</a>
```

You didn't add `target="_blank"` to the anchor.

I tried adding the attribute through my console in Chrome, and it works as expected.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: Read his code, it has the `target="_blank"`

Comment: No it bloody well doesn't. Did you visit his site?! It looks like this: `<a href=​"http:​/​/​jahde.co/​stream/​sample-page/​">​About Me​</a>`

Comment: This is the correct answer. The provided code here doesn't match the source code on the provided problematic site. +1

Comment: No, I read the code he posted. If he posted incorrect code above then he should fix it.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Good eye, Jezen!